# UMLGraph Installation on Mac

Tags: umlgraph

I am trying to get UMLGraph complied on my MacBook Pro(OSX 10.9.5) and getting an error when trying to run 'ant build.xml'.  Has anyone had this issue?  Here is the error:

```
UMLGraph-5.7_2.3-SNAPSHOT$ ant build.xml
Buildfile: /Users/jeremy/UMLGraph-5.7_2.3-SNAPSHOT/build.xml
[echo] git describe --abbrev=6 => 'version'

BUILD FAILED
/Users/jeremy/UMLGraph-5.7_2.3-SNAPSHOT/build.xml:50: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/jeremy/UMLGraph-5.7_2.3-SNAPSHOT/build.xml:27: exec returned: 128

Total time: 1 second
```

Here is a snip of line 50 and a few lines above it from build.xml:

```
 23   <sequential>
 24     <echo message="git describe --abbrev=6 => '@{outputproperty}'"/>
 25   <exec executable="git"
 26     failonerror="true"
 27     outputproperty="@{outputproperty}">
 28     <arg value="describe"/>
 29     <arg value="--abbrev=6"/>
 30     <arg value="HEAD"/>
 31     <redirector>
 32       <outputfilterchain>
 33       <tokenfilter>
 34         <replaceregex pattern="R" replace=""/>
 35         <replaceregex pattern="_" replace="."/>
 36         <replaceregex pattern="-" replace="."/>
 37         <replaceregex pattern="(-.*)$" replace="-SNAPSHOT"/>
 38       </tokenfilter>
 39       </outputfilterchain>
 40     </redirector>
 41     </exec>
 42     <echo message="gitversion returned '${@{outputproperty}}'"/>
 43   </sequential>
 44 </macrodef>
 45 
 46 <!-- define Maven coordinates; see https://docs.sonatype.org/display/Repository/Sonatype+OSS+Maven+Repository+Usage+Guide#SonatypeOSSMavenRepositoryUsageGuide-7c.DeploySnaps    hotsandStageReleaseswithAnt -->
 47 <property name="groupId" value="org.umlgraph" />
 48 <property name="artifactId" value="UmlGraph" />
 49 <!-- <property name="version" value="1.0-SNAPSHOT" /> -->
 50 <gitversion outputproperty="version"/>
```

Here are the instructions in the README.txt:

```
UMLGraph - Declarative Drawing of UML Diagrams

UMLGraph allows the declarative specification and drawing of
UML class and sequence diagrams.  You can browse the system's
documentation from the doc/index.html page, or print it from
doc/indexw.html.

To install the elements required to run UMLGraph, simply copy
the contents of the lib directory to a location consistent with
your installation's conventions (for example to /usr/local/lib).

To compile the Java doclet from the source code run ant on the
build.xml file.

If you change the source code, you can run regression tests by
executing "ant test".

Project home page: http://www.umlgraph.org
GitHub page: git@github.com:dspinellis/UMLGraph.git

Diomidis Spinellis - November 2005, August 2008, April 2012
```

I copied the files from lib/ to /usr/local/lib, like the instructions said, but it appears I am not building it correctly.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: - Is Git installed?
- Is the git command in your PATH?
- Are you running ant within a directory that has been cloned with Git?

Comment: Yes, Git is installed and is in my path.  I am running ant in the directory that was created when I unzipped the project.  So no, I did not clone from github.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the project compiled you must clone it from GitHub.  This is required in order to obtain the version string.